# Examples of Geometric Constructions in Higher Dimensions

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

The classical problem of geometric construction seems to be restricted to planar Euclidean Geometry with straight edge and compass as the only admissible "construction-tools".

I would like to know, whether geometric construction in $n$-dimensional Euclidean (or even non-euclidean) Geometry has ever seriously been investigated, using $k$-dimensional hyper planes or hyper spheres as generalisations of pointsets constructible with straight edge or compass, and their pairwise intersections as admissible construction steps.

The concrete problem that I am interested in, is the construction of an ellipsoid's principal axes from a set of its conjugate diameters; in the planar case that is possible via the method of Rytz and I would like to know if that method generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: There was some work done for hyperbolic plane and the sphere. Both in dimension 2.